# Отрицательный результат из DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Итак есть активити, на ней кнопка Старт, по нажатию на кнопку запускается DialogFragment.
В DialogFragment один едитТекст и 2 кнопки(Ок, Отмена). Нужен диалог для ввода пароля. Если пароль введен то запускается сервис (запуск сервиса написан на кнопке старт). Если отмена, я хочу что бы код после вызова диалога не выполнялся(вызов сервиса). Не могу придумать корректный способ получить из диалога отмену. Пока что подумал что бы по кнопке отмена кидалось исключение, но кажется это не корректно будет.

Comment: а не проще запускать сервис после правильного пароля? ведь в ином случае вам его останавливать необходимо, по мне так вы сразу решаете две проблемы. Если нет просто остановите сервис.

Comment: можно получать любые данные из DialogFragment через интерфейс

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich какой?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В классе `DialogFragment`:

```
 public interface OnButtonClick {
    void onDialogClickListener(int action, int type);
 }

OnButtonClick onClick;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        onClick = (OnButtonClick) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onDialogClickListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    onClick = null;
}
```

В `MainActivity`:

```
...extends AppCompatActivity implements MyDialog.OnButtonClick {...

@Override
public void onDialogClickListener(int action, int type) {}
```

Использование: в `DialogFragment` в нужный момент -

```
 onClick.onDialogClickListener(action, type);
```

передавать можно абсолютно любые данные.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Но что бы у меня заработало мне пришлось изменить метод Attach:
<pre>
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach((Activity) activity);
        try {
            onClick1 = (OnButtonClick) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onDialogClickListener");
        }
    }</pre>

Comment: Да действительно хорошее решение, но нужно подкоректировать ответ и поменять `context` на `activity`

Comment: А как при таком подходе достать строку из `EditText` ? Вот у меня тут вопрос мне как раз нужно с помощью вашего ответа передать эту строку             http://goo.gl/trDVTR           . Посоветуйте как сделать...

Comment: если я правильно понял, про что вы, то обычным способом: `String myText = myEditText.getText().toString()` и в интерфейсе передавать этот `String` вместо `int`