# Передача строки из PagerFragment в Activity

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

В программе используеться `ViewPager`, и нужно из `PagerFragmet` передать `String` в `MainActivity`.

Нужно из `PagerFragment` передать `String` `(userp2s)` в `MainActivity`

В `String` записываются данные из `edittext.addTextChangedListener`, а в `Activity` эта строка записывается в БД.(Для понимания - добавлю код)

`PageFragment.java`:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
               /*......
                .......
                .......*/

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;

    DB db;

    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";

    int pageNumber;

    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View view = null;
        switch (pageNumber) {
            case 0:
//-----------------------------------------Users View----------------------------------------------
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users, null);
                userp2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.user_phone_2_et);
                /*......
                .......
                .......*/
                }
                userp2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                        userp2s = "01" + userp2.getText().toString() + "%";
                    }
                });

                db.close();
                break;
            case 1:
//-----------------------------------------System View----------------------------------------------
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.system, null);
                /*......
                .......
                .......*/
                break;
            case 2:
//-----------------------------------------Input Output View----------------------------------------
                /*......
                .......
                .......*/
                break;
            case 3:
//-----------------------------------Other text-----------------------------------------------------
                /*......
                .......
                .......*/
                }
                break;
        }


        return view;
    }
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
private int prevPage = -1;
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                prevPage = pager.getCurrentItem();
                Log.d(TAG, "PrevPage = " + prevPage);
            }
            if (prevPage == 0) {
//--------------------------------------------Users Tab---------------------------------------------
                db = new DB(this);
                db.open();
              /*..........
              ...........
              ..........*/




                db.UserSMSUpdRec(name, userp2s,/*..........*/, id);

                db.close();
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте данные с помощью интерфейса. Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498412/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-dialogfragment/498796#498796) как это делать. Только вместо Диалога используйте свой обычный фрагмент.

Comment: как это подставить в `onCreateView`?

Comment: в `onCreateView` ничего не надо ставить. Инициализация идет на `onAttach`,  вызов `onClick.onDialogClickListener(action, type);` - в любом нужном месте