# Как закрыть DialogFragment с передачей данных в Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Я работаю с `DialogFragment` в который передаю свой `layout` с двумя кнопками(`ok`, `cansel`), к этим кнопкам привязываю лисенер и все работает, но как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку допустим `ok` диалог закрывался перед этим отправляя результат в активити которое его вызвало? Допустим как когда мы делаем `startActivityFotResult();` ... Но в случае с `DialogFragment` я не могу использовать `startActivityFotResult();`...

**Что делать?**

Вот код :

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

final String LOG_TAG = "MyDialog";
int layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    layout = args.getInt("layout");
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

    LinearLayout llSent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSent);
    LinearLayout llSkip = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSkip);

    llSent.setOnClickListener(listener);
    llSkip.setOnClickListener(listener);
    adb.setView(view);

    return adb.create();
}

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.llSent:
                System.out.println("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
                break;
            case R.id.llSkip:
                System.out.println("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
                break;
        }
    }
};

public void dismissDialog(final MyDialog dialog, int daleyTime) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, daleyTime);
}

public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onDismiss");
}

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onCancel");
}

public static MyDialog newInstance(int layout) {
    MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    myDialog.setArguments(args);

    return myDialog;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Я сделал так, инициализируем обьект с помощью этой функции

```
public static MyDialog newInstance(int layout) {
    myDialog = new MyDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    myDialog.setArguments(args);

    return myDialog;
}
```

и переменную myDialog я сохранил глобально как статическую

```
private static MyDialog myDialog;
```

теперь это выглядит так

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

final String LOG_TAG = "MyDialog";
private static MyDialog myDialog;

int layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    layout = args.getInt("layout");
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

    if (layout == R.layout.activity_note_dialog) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        LinearLayout llSent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSent);
        LinearLayout llSkip = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSkip);

        llSent.setOnClickListener(listener);
        llSkip.setOnClickListener(listener);
        adb.setView(view);
    }

    return adb.create();
}

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.llSent:
                System.out.println("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
                myDialog.dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.llSkip:
                System.out.println("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
                myDialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
};

public void dismissDialog(final MyDialog dialog, int daleyTime) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, daleyTime);
}

public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onDismiss");
}

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onCancel");
}

public static MyDialog newInstance(int layout) {
    myDialog = new MyDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    myDialog.setArguments(args);

    return myDialog;
}
}
```

И все работает...

Answer (score 3):

Например, [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498412/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-dialogfragment/498796#498796).

Только после вызова `onClick.onDialogClickListener(action, type);` вызвать `dismiss();`

Answer (score -1):

Почему не можете?

```
getActivity.startActivityFotResult();
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос то я не могу стартануть активити так потому, что для того, чтоб показать диалог я сначала должен инициализировать обьект, а  потом на нем уже вызнать `show()` , вот код MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(R.layout.activity_dialog);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");   Как можно в этом случае стартануть ?