# Как вернуть значения из DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть кстомный `DialogFragment` и вопрос вот в чем... Есть активити которое с помощью метода `newInstance(int layout)` получает экземпляр класса `new MyDialog()` в `layout` которого есть 2 кнопки, на которых висит лисенер и слушает нажатия. Сейчас при нажатии на кнопку `DialogFragment` просто закрывается... Вот я не могу догадаться как мне сделать так, чтоб он перед закрытие возвращал в вызвавшее его активити значения(допустим стринг строку) .

**Вот код :**

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

final String LOG_TAG = "MyDialog";
private static MyDialog myDialog;

int layout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();
    layout = args.getInt("layout");
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(layout)
            .setCancelable(true);

    if (layout == R.layout.activity_note_dialog) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        LinearLayout llSent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSent);
        LinearLayout llSkip = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llSkip);

        llSent.setOnClickListener(listener);
        llSkip.setOnClickListener(listener);
        adb.setView(view);
    }

    return adb.create();
}

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.llSent:
                System.out.println("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
                myDialog.dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.llSkip:
                System.out.println("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
                myDialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
};

public void dismissDialog(final MyDialog dialog, int daleyTime) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, daleyTime);
}

public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onDismiss");
}

public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onCancel");
}

public static MyDialog newInstance(int layout) {
    myDialog = new MyDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    myDialog.setArguments(args);

    return myDialog;
}
}
```

**Подскажите как это сделать?**

Comment: Вам же дали ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514759/6520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге сделал через интерфейс спасибо @Abrog Petrovich ответ [здесь был](http://goo.gl/AcvfUy),

Суть вот :

В классе `DialogFragment`:

```
 public interface OnButtonClick {
    void onDialogClickListener(int action, int type);
 }

OnButtonClick onClick;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        onClick = (OnButtonClick) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onDialogClickListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    onClick = null;
}
```

В `MainActivity`:

```
...extends AppCompatActivity implements MyDialog.OnButtonClick {...

@Override
public void onDialogClickListener(int action, int type) {}
```

Использование: в `DialogFragment` в нужный момент -

```
 onClick.onDialogClickListener(action, type);
```

передавать можно абсолютно любые данные.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить свой интерфейс, у Диалога сделать для него сеттер, в активити устанавливаете интерфейс в переопределенном методе пишите все что вам нужно, а в диалоге вызываете этот метод по нажатию на кнопке.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, в в активити написать к-л метод, с к-л аргументами и его вызвать из диалога скастовав результат вызова `getActivity()` к конкретному классу вашей активити:

В классе диалога:

```
((ActivityClassName)getActivity()).someMethodName(someArg);
```

В классе активити:

```
public void someMethodName(SomeArgType someArg){
    Log.d("TAG", someArg.toString());
}
```

Comment: Не очень хороший вариант

Comment: @artemiygreg, ну, как вариант, всё же, может помочь. Хоть и да - с интерфейсом - лучше)

Comment: как вариант да можно сделать работать будет, но сам подход плохой, допустим потом нужно будет еще в двух активити сделать тоже самое и как такое реализовать, проверки через instanceof?))

Comment: @artemiygreg, просто сделать абстрактную базовую активити, в ней сей метод определить и к ней кастовать - никаких instanceof не понадобится)))

Comment: а если потом еще понадобится из фрагмента вызвать?

Comment: @artemiygreg, ну так я ж и говорю - интерфейсом лучше. И не только говорю, но ещё и плюс поставил. Но, как по себе помню, интерфейсы - сложно и новичкам лучше вот как я предложил поначалу сделать - быстро и понятно. Хоть и не совсем верно, да.