# ViewPager. Переход на следующий элемент по нажатию

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть `ViewPager` у которого отключен скрол. Хочу по нажатию на `ViewPager` переходить на следующую страницу.

вот мой фрагмент:

```
public SelectFragment() {
    }

    public static SelectFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, int id) {
        SelectFragment fragment = new SelectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        args.putInt("idGroup", id);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select, container, false);
        pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById();

        String id = getString(R.string.kalima, getArguments().getInt("idGroup"));
        String page = getString(R.string.kalima, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));


        textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textSelect);
        imageone = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectOne);
        imagetwo = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSelecttwo);

        imageone.setOnClickListener(this);
        imagetwo.setOnClickListener(this);

        _select = DataServer.getSelectData(Integer.parseInt(id),getActivity());
        textView.setText(_select.get(Integer.parseInt(page)).getKalima());
        imageselect.setImageResource(R.mipmap.animation_img1);

        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        String s = button.getText().toString();
        String t = textView.getTag().toString();
        if (s.equals(t)) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(1);

        }

    }
```

код адаптера:

```
public class KalimaPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int idGroup;

public KalimaPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int id) {
    super(fm);
    idGroup = id;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return SelectFragment.newInstance(position, idGroup);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: getCurrentItem() постаянно   вернёт 0

Comment: Если к ViewPager подключен адаптер с фрагментами, то `pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1)` должно работать. С проверкой граничных значений, конечно.

Comment: ошибка в этом строке. pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1)   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.pager.ViewPager.getCurrentItem()' on a null object reference

Comment: а покажите код адаптера?

Comment: интересная реализация :) не знаю, работает ли она, поэтому рекомендую сделать через interface (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498412/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-dialogfragment/498796#498796) и менять страницу в активности, где `pager` прописывался.

Comment: а можноли какта обработат нажатие  Button - а в Activity

Comment: вы обрабатывайте как и сделали во фрагменте. Просто результат (номер страницы) через интерфэйс в активити передавайте. `myInterface.setPage(number)` Чтобы не изобретать велосипед + полезный навык