# Переход из одного фрагмента в другой при нажатии на кнопку в listview

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `listvew` с кастамным адаптером, в котором находится `Textview`, `CheckBox` и кнопка.
Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на `imaginbutton imbutUpd`, фрагмент где находится `listview` заменился новым фрагментом.
Код `BaseAdapter`

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter    {

ArrayList<ListBase> listBases;
Context context;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListBase> araylv){
    if(araylv != null){
        listBases = araylv;
    }
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listBases.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int number) {
    return listBases.get(number);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}


 private  DBMethods dbMethods;
CheckBox checkDel;

ImageButton imbutUpd;
BussinesRecrods bussinesRecrods;

MainActivity main;

int isTag;
@Override
public View getView(int id, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

   ListBase p = getProduct(id);

    bussinesRecrods = new BussinesRecrods();

    dbMethods = new DBMethods(context);
    main = new MainActivity();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tableinfact, parent, false);
    }

    TextView textVNotBook = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVNotBook);
    TextView textTimeDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDateTime);
    checkDel = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBNotBook);
    imbutUpd = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButUpdate);

    textVNotBook.setText(listBases.get(id).textHave);
    textTimeDate.setText(listBases.get(id).textTime+ " "+listBases.get(id).textDate);

    checkDel.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangeList);
    checkDel.setTag(id);
    checkDel.setChecked(p.box);
    imbutUpd.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    imbutUpd.setTag(id);

    return convertView;
}


View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    }

};

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смена фрагмента должна производиться не в адаптере, а в активности, в которой фрагмент и находится.

Здесь два варианта:

1. Если у вас адаптер в классе активности, просто вызывайте из активности такую функцию:

   ```
   void changeFragment(int number) {
       FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       ft.replace(idContainer, new MyFragment());
       //или
       ft.replace(idContainer, MyFragment.newInstance(number));

       ft.commit();
   }
   ```
2. Если у вас адаптер в отдельном классе, вызывайте эту функцию через `interface` в классе адаптера:

   ```
   ChangeFragment clickOnItem;

   interface ChangeFragment{
       void changeFragment(int number);
   }

   public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListBase> araylv){
       if(araylv != null){
           listBases = araylv;
       }
       this.context = context;
       clickOnItem = (ClickOnItem) context;
   }
   ```

Вызывать на клике `clickOnItem.changeFragment(id)`, а в активности: `MyActivity implements ListViewAdapter.ChangeFragment`и `@Override` функцию из варианта №1.

Вообще, сейчас `ListView` считается устаревшим и рекомендуется использовать `RecyclerView`. Он и правда проще, лучше и функциональней.

Comment: А как поместить обработчик нажатия кнопки listview, в класс активности?

Comment: у вас адаптер в отдельном классе или нет?

Comment: Адаптер в отдельном классе

Comment: тогда с помощью интерфэйса. Например, вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498412/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-dialogfragment/498796#498796. Только инициализируйте переменную интерфэйса в конструкторе адаптера, а не в `onAttach`.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, привести в пример код уже с инициализированным интерфейсом в конструкторе адаптера , и переопределённым  методом интерфейса в активити.

Comment: посмотрите, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает. Но в варианте №1 метод newInstance принимает только string переменные в параметр, поэтому я использовал ft.replace(idContainer, new MyFragment());

Comment: `newInstance() ` можно переписать как угодно, по типу заданного. Вообще это правильный (единственный) способ передавать во фрагменты информацию на этапе их создания.

Comment: Метод newInstance() можно заменить конструктором класса фрагмента?

Comment: Лучше не стоит. `newInstanse()` - статический. При замене на конструктор возможны непредсказуемые ошибки. Но можно написать много `newInstance` (сколько надо), с учетом что каждый будет принимать разные аргументы