# Как мне из "Fragment" поменять цвет чего-либо в Activity

Tags: java, android

Я имею основной Activity: MainMenu

И Фрагмент: Settings

Как мне из Settings поменять цвет чего-либо в MainMenu

P.S цвет XML который привязан к MainMenu

Comment: сделайте с помощью интерфейса. Посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498412/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-dialogfragment/498796#498796

Answer (score 1):

Из фрагмента можно обращаться в активность через вот такую конструкцию:

```
((MainMenu)getActivity())
```

Чтобы изменить какой-либо элемент, обратитесь к нему примерно так

```
((MainMenu)getActivity()).someElement.setColor(red);
```

Comment: А если не из фрагмента?

Comment: Что я должен вставить в "someElement" если мой объект имеет id "main_nav"

Comment: findViewById(R.id.main_nav)