# Работа с фрагментом из dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть фрагмент в котором размещен список, на текущий момент я пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию списка. Данный список я получаю с сервера. Фильтровать список я могу из DialogFragment который открывается из этого же фрагмента. Вот как я вызываю фрагмент из диалога:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(data));
                dismiss();
                JobList jobList = new JobList();
                jobList.testFunction(view, data);
            }
        });
```

и вот вызываемая в фрагменте функция:

```
public void testFunction(View view, HashMap<String, String> data) {
       mMenu = getmMenu();
        sp = Objects.requireNonNull(view.getContext()).getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
        ms = MySingleton.getInstance();
        rootView = view;
        long val = MySingleton.getInstance().time() - sp.getLong("expires_in", 0);
        if (val > 30) {
            MySingleton.getInstance().updateToken(sp.getString("refresh_token", ""), 11);
        } else {
            getL_jobs(ms.getOffset(), ms.getJ_type(), sp.getString("access_token", ""), data);
        }


    }
```

я столкнулся с двумя на текущий момент проблемами:

1. Не видится меню в тулбаре.
2. Не видится recyclerView в функции получения списка.

Эти две проблемы связаны с тем что у меня вроде как не инициализированы элементы меню и виджет списка. Я вижу два варианта:

1. Жесткое пересоздание фрагмента, с прописыванием данных фильтра.
2. Повторное присвоение значений виджету и меню.

Я не могу понять каким образом можно пересоздать фрагмент из самого фрагмента нормально, либо как вообще решить сложившуюся ситуацию. Весь день сижу и не могу найти нормальное решение. Пробовал пересоздвать фрагмент, но у меня не получилось этого сделать. Заранее благодарен за помощь и ценные советы.

Comment: передавать данные между фрагментами лучше через активность с помощью интерфейса

Comment: @Jarvis_J, это как вообще?? такое можно делать как-то? у меня в программе есть только один интерфейс и он используется для хранения адресов запросов на сервер, можете более подробно написать, если вам не сложно?

Comment: Здесь писал про интерфейс: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498412/Отрицательный-результат-из-dialogfragment/498796#498796 . На получении данных в активити просто организуйте работу с другим фрагментом

Comment: жаль что нельзя вам два плюса поставить)) спасибо большое за помощь :)