# Вывод текста из DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

У меня есть кнопка, вызывающая диалоговое окно, в котором есть два поля для ввода. Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия на PositiveButton выводилось в TextView содержимое диалога. Но я никак не могу понять, как из диалога достать информацию.

```
public class AddDialog extends DialogFragment {
private Editable InputText;
public interface AddDialogListener{
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

AddDialogListener mListener;
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View v = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.add_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    final EditText title =(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    final EditText cost = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.cost_text);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.add_income_title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.add_button_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    AddDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Класс фрагмента, куда должна выводиться информация

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements AddDialog.AddDialogListener{
private Button mPlusButton;
private TextView mTest;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UUID budgetId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_BUDGET_ID);
    mBudget = BudgetList.get(getActivity()).getBudget(budgetId);
}

public void showDialog(){
    AddDialog addDialog = new AddDialog();
    addDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddDialog");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.budget_detail, container, false);
    mTest = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mPlusButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.plus_button);
    mPlusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
}

@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

}

}
```

Comment: Самое простое - это интерфейсом.

Comment: В методе `onDialogPositiveClick` заменяете параметр на текст, а потом из диалога, по нажатию кнопки вызываете этот метод, что-то вроде `mListener .onDialogPositiveClick(title.getText().toString())`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498412/Отрицательный-результат-из-dialogfragment/498796#498796